# How run Openxenmanager in Manjaro 17?

Tags: manjaro

When its Run, it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openxenmanager", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('openxenmanager==0.1b1', 'openxenmanager')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 741, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1502, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openxenmanager-0.1b1-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/openxenmanager", line 23, in <module>
    import gtk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gtk'
```

Comment: Would you please detail better your problem? The question might be closed as unclear otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

See the requirements listed at 
https://github.com/OpenXenManager/openxenmanager

It clearly says Python 2.7, 
whereas your stacktrace indicates Python 3.6 is installed.
You can verify this with `python -V`.

Both versions of Python can exist together (I have them both installed).
`/usr/bin/openxenmanager` is just a short shell script that invokes an unqualified `python`.  It might be sufficient to change the version of python there; you could test with
`cd /usr/share/openxenmanager; python2.7 window.py`.

If there are other environmental dependencies assumed you might need to operate in a virtual env; see

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python/Virtual_environment